Why does my cloth simulation not settle properly?
After the character spins quickly, the cloth gets stuck upwards as if it's sticking to the body. What can I do to fix this while maintaining the same poly-count? Provided are screenshots of all of my cloth & collision settings

The character is 5.15m tall.
Cloth:


Adjusting the Collision Distances did not seem to solve the problem.
Collider (The Character Body):

Blend File:
https://mega.nz/file/pKMGgZyT#Q63wgYzkxHsD714S_Qcf1hsTb-p3PPWWbwfAqhWwzB4
(Silk Preset, 30 Quality steps)
(Pin Group, Stiffness 1)
(8 Collisions Quality steps)
(Object Collide distance: 0.001)
(Self Collide distance: 0.001)
(Collider Damping: 0.100)
(Thickness Outer: 0.001)
(Inner: 0.200)
(Friction: 5.000)

i just changed to the preset: cotton


